# PHP Format USD Currency - Negative Numbers

Tags: php, regex, string-formatting, money-format

I need to display a sum of money with the minus symbol before the `$` sign if it's a negative number.

E.g.:

```
$sum="-120";
echo "$".$sum;
```

Output will be:

```
$-120
```

I want the output to be:

```
-$120
```

I could do it with *regex*/*str_replace*/etc, but i wonder if there is a built-in PHP function for that. Maybe some option in `money_format` or something similar.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`money_format()` will do this, but you need to use `setlocale()` first to ensure that the currency symbol is correctly set:

```
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_US');
echo money_format('%+n', -123.45); // -$123.45
```

References:

- [setlocale()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php)
- [money_format()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php)

Comment: Thanks, Works on server. There is way to make this function work on localhost in windows?

Comment: Warning: This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 7.4.0, and REMOVED as of PHP 8.0.0. Relying on this function is highly discouraged.

Answer (score 1):

if intl is installed on your php config, you can do that too:

```
$fmt = new NumberFormatter('en_US', NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
echo $fmt->formatCurrency($sum, "USD");
```

Comment: Thanks. But this returns the number inside (123) not -123.

Comment: @batz: it works for me in php 5.5, however I have read in the php manual *(in comments)*  that since 5.6 it returns this strange format enclosed with parenthesis with `en_US` (is it a bug?). Perhaps you can obtain the expected result with an other local than `en_US`